# how to correct Azure SQL DB Trigger error

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I wrote an `AFTER INSERT` Trigger in my Azure SQL DB, which works just fine from within SSMS.

However, I am working with a JavaScript developer creating an application which writes to the Parent Table. The calling application needs to capture what was actually inserted.  So, the Javascript statement is: `Insert Into {my Table]... OUTPUT INSERTED.* Values (....`.  The T-SQL `OUTPUT` clause description specifically states "Triggers cannot be defined on the target."

Does anyone have suggestions for another way around this limitation?  Do we have write a Procedure to query the Parent and Insert Into the Child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DML statements cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an `OUTPUT` clause without any `INTO` clause.

There's [an article about this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/07/11/update-with-output-clause-triggers-and-sqlmoreresults/) on the Microsoft SQL Programmability & API Development Team Blog.